# Problems using Python to solve coupled delay differential equations (DDEs)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to use `pydelay` library to solve a system of delay differential equations. I have followed [instructions](http://pydelay.sourceforge.net/) to setup my model. However, I ran into some errors and really appreciate any suggestions.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from pydelay import dde23

# define the equations
eqns = { 
    'B' : 'L*((D*D/(D*D+b*b))*(H/(H+v)))- w*B',
    'H' : 'w*B(t-tau) - H*(a_min + a_max*(b*b/(b*b+D*D))-s*(F/(F-H)))',
    'F' : 'H*(a_min + a_max*(b*b/(b*b+D*D))-s*(F/(F-H))) - m*F',
    'D' : 'c*F - r_a*(F+H) - r_b*B'
    }

#define the parameters
params = {
    'L' : 2000.0,       # laying rate
    'b' : 500,  # 
    'w' : 1.0/9,  # pupation rate of brood
    'tau' : 12.0, # time lag
    'a_min' : 0.25,  # 
    'a_max' : 0.25,
    's' : 0.75,
    'm' : 0.3,
    'c' : 0.10,
    'r_a' : 0.007,
    'r_b' : 0.018,
    'v' : 5000.0
    }

# Initialise the solver
dde = dde23(eqns=eqns, params=params)

# set the simulation parameters 
dde.set_sim_params(tfinal=50, dtmax=1.0)

# set the history
n=12
t_hist = np.linspace(0, n, n)
B_hist = np.array([5] * n)
H_hist = np.array([20] * n)
F_hist = np.array([10] * n)
D_hist = np.array([100] * n)

histdic = {
    't': t_hist,
    'B': B_hist,
    'H': H_hist,
    'F': F_hist,
    'D': D_hist,
}
dde.hist_from_arrays(histdic)

# run the simulator
dde.run()
```

The errors I ran into were:

```
Number of Minimum steps taken: 23090
Error: Scipy could not calculate spline for variable H.
Error: Scipy could not calculate spline for variable B.
Error: Scipy could not calculate spline for variable D.
Error: Scipy could not calculate spline for variable F.
```

Comment: Your code runs fine here. pydelay 0.1.1, numpy 1.7.1, run from an interactive qtconsole, ipython 1.1.0, OSX.

Comment: Try running an example of the docs to check if your system is broken first

Comment: @flebool: Thanks for the reply. I am able to run the examples without any problem....

Comment: Off the top of my head, there's something wrong with your libraries versions (have you compared them with mine?) or the interpolation problem may be related for example to an infinity. if you turn on `%pdb` in ipython and run your script with `%run -i myscript.py`, and backtrace a little from the crash, you should be able to see if there are any `Inf` in the data to be interpolated

Comment: @flebool: Thanks for your suggestion. It is working now in iPython. I think another trick is to set the min time step as well.